# Handling potential ++ in regular expression that is currently throwing an execption

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of keywords (that are dynamically generated) that are iterated over and inserted into a regular expression.

For example:

```
const keywords = ['Pascal', 'Elixir', 'A++', 'Elm'];

keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
  const reg = new RegExp(`\\b(${keyword})\\b`, 'ig');

  ... do stuff with regex here ...
});
```

This pattern is fine except in the case of A++ (or C++ or any other potential comparable variation), where I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\b($a++)\b/: Nothing to repeat
```

Given that I don't know what the specific values are at runtime, how would I handle this edge case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape regular expression special characters.

In your case it is `A++`

where you need to `A\+\+`

As you don't know what is going to be there in the list so before you use any of those dynamic string as a part of regex you may use some sanitizer to escape special characters.

For a head start you may use something like this:

```js
function escSpecialChars(str){
  return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

const keywords = ['Pascal', 'Elixir', 'A++', 'Elm'];

keywords.forEach((keyword) => {
  //console.log(keyword);// remove this later
  var tmpReg=escSpecialChars(keyword);
  //console.log(tmpReg); // remove this later
  var pattern = "\\b"+tmpReg+"(?=\\s|$)";
  var re = new RegExp(pattern);
  
  console.log(re.exec("Pascal Elixir cascel Elm A++"));
  
  
  // do your stuff here

});
```

List of special meaning characters of regular expression can be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here's what I'm trying to fix though:

The regular expression I end up with for this keyword looks like this: `/\b(A\+\+)\b/gi` (via `const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${tmpReg})\\b`, 'ig');`)

But then both `"A\+\+".match(regex)` AND `"A++".match(regex)` return `null`. How do I actually use the properly escaped keyword to match on other strings?

Comment: @TheNovice I have updated the answer with an workng solution plz check...

Comment: Wow!! Thank you SO much for that. That's enormously helpful.

Comment: Can you explain to me what is happening with `(?=\\s|$)`? I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `+` is a special character in a regex and it means `the previous character, 1 or more times`. Two `+` characters in a row is a syntax error. If you are dynamically populating a regex with strings you need to make that those strings are valid regex strings.

You can either dynamically escape them (look through the string, find special characters and prefix them with a `\`), or you can make sure that they are valid regex strings before they get to your program.

Also, you use the `\b` word boundary character in your regex. A `+` character is not a word character so the regex `\bA\+\+\b` will not match the string `A++`. There is no word boundary after a `+` character. You might have to rethink your main regex.